Copy and repeat or copy and sum integer coefficients

Let
$$
\ell(n) = \left\lfloor\log_2 n\right\rfloor.
$$
Let $T(n,k)$ be an integer coefficients with row length $f(n)$ (number of zeros in the binary expansion of $n$ plus $2$ for $n>0$ with $f(0)=1$) such that
$$
T(n, k) = \begin{cases}
1 & \textrm{if } n = 0, k = 1 \\
1 & \textrm{if } n = 1, k = 1 \\
1 & \textrm{if } n = 1, k = 2 \\
T(n-2^{\ell(n)-1},k) & \textrm{if } n < 3\cdot2^{\ell(n)-1}, 1 \leqslant k < f(n) \\
T(n-2^{\ell(n)-1},f(n)-1) & \textrm{if } n < 3\cdot2^{\ell(n)-1}, k = f(n) \\
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} iT(n-2^{\ell(n)},k) & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Let $a(n)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$
a(n) = T(n, f(n)).
$$
Let $s(n)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$
s(n) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2^n-1} a(i).
$$

I conjecture that $s(n)$ is somehow related with Laguerre polynomials.
Is there a way to get a nice closed form or generating function for $s(n)$?

"somehow related". been slacking? :P

I continue to work on it, but there is no result yet.
